# Permutation of 6-digit numbers without repetition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

How  many 6-digit numbers without repetition of digits are there such that 
a ) the digits are all non-zero 
b ) 1 and 2 do not appear consecutively in either order ?

Calculated the answer as below 
I : number of 6-digit numbers such that all digits are non-zero is 
**p(9,6)**
II : number of 6-digit numbers in which 1 and 2 do not appear consecutively in either order is 
**7 * p(4,2)**
Final answer would be  **p(9,6)** - **7 * p(4,2)** = 60936

But the answer is 52080.How come?

Comment: In b) is it still true that the digits are non-zero?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes.Both of them together form a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be subtracting the number of 6 digit numbers that do have 1 and 2 together in some order. There are two possible orders for 1 and 2 , and 5 possible places you can put them, then you need to fill the 4 remaining positions using the 7 remaining digits.

so instead of $7*P^4_2$ you should have

$$ 2 * 5 * P^7_4 $$  (this does give the correct answer)

Answer (score 2):

> The digits are all non-zero:

- Choose $6$ symbols from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and permute them: $\binom{9}{6}\cdot6!=60480$

> $1$ and $2$ do not appear consecutively in either order:

- Choose $4$ symbols from $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, add $12$ and permute them: $\binom{7}{4}\cdot5!=4200$
- Choose $4$ symbols from $\{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, add $21$ and permute them: $\binom{7}{4}\cdot5!=4200$

---

Finally, subtract the sum of the latter from the former: $60480-(4200+4200)=52080$

Comment: Great explanation.Thank you.!

Comment: @Pradeep: You're welcome :)